# How to display and edit image inside Vuetify Data tables

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, datatables, vuetify.js

I have some data inside **Vuetify** data-tables. I would like to return in every row a small dessert image/s. I don't know how to insert HTML inside *Photo column* and how to return an image. I use a v-dialog to edit text data, so I would like to edit also a specific photo by file input. With basic text I do not have any problem. Could someone help with this problem?

**Demo:**
https://codepen.io/noobmaster2137/pen/qBqdwXN

**Example:**
Screenshot

[image]

**HTML:**

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-data-table
      :headers="headers"
      :items="desserts"
      sort-by="calories"
      class="elevation-1"
    >
      <template v-slot:top>
        <v-toolbar
          flat
        >
          <v-toolbar-title>Desserts</v-toolbar-title>
          <v-divider
            class="mx-4"
            inset
            vertical
          ></v-divider>
          <v-spacer></v-spacer>
          <v-dialog
            v-model="dialog"
            max-width="500px"
          >
            <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
              <v-btn
                color="primary"
                dark
                class="mb-2"
                v-bind="attrs"
                v-on="on"
              >
                New Item
              </v-btn>
            </template>
            <v-card>
              <v-card-title>
                <span class="headline">{{ formTitle }}</span>
              </v-card-title>
  
              <v-card-text>
                <v-container>
                  <v-row>
                    <v-col
                      cols="12"
                      sm="6"
                      md="4"
                    >
                      <v-text-field
                        v-model="editedItem.name"
                        label="Dessert name"
                      ></v-text-field>
                    </v-col>
                    <v-col
                      cols="12"
                      sm="6"
                      md="4"
                    >
                      <v-text-field
                        v-model="editedItem.calories"
                        label="Calories"
                      ></v-text-field>
                    </v-col>
                    <v-col
                      cols="12"
                      sm="6"
                      md="4"
                    >
                      <v-text-field
                        v-model="editedItem.fat"
                        label="Fat (g)"
                      ></v-text-field>
                    </v-col>
                    <v-col
                      cols="12"
                      sm="6"
                      md="4"
                    >
                      <v-text-field
                        v-model="editedItem.carbs"
                        label="Carbs (g)"
                      ></v-text-field>
                    </v-col>
                    <v-col
                      cols="12"
                      sm="6"
                      md="4"
                    >
                      <v-text-field
                        v-model="editedItem.protein"
                        label="Protein (g)"
                      ></v-text-field>
                    </v-col>
                    <v-col
                      cols="12"
                      sm="12"
                      md="12"
                    >
                      <v-file-input
                        label="Photo"
                        v-model="editedItem.photoURL"
                        show-size
                        small-chips
                        truncate-length="15"
                      ></v-file-input>
                    </v-col>
                  </v-row>
                </v-container>
              </v-card-text>
  
              <v-card-actions>
                <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                <v-btn
                  color="blue darken-1"
                  text
                  @click="close"
                >
                  Cancel
                </v-btn>
                <v-btn
                  color="blue darken-1"
                  text
                  @click="save"
                >
                  Save
                </v-btn>
              </v-card-actions>
            </v-card>
          </v-dialog>
          <v-dialog v-model="dialogDelete" max-width="500px">
            <v-card>
              <v-card-title class="headline">Are you sure you want to delete this item?</v-card-title>
              <v-card-actions>
                <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                <v-btn color="blue darken-1" text @click="closeDelete">Cancel</v-btn>
                <v-btn color="blue darken-1" text @click="deleteItemConfirm">OK</v-btn>
                <v-spacer></v-spacer>
              </v-card-actions>
            </v-card>
          </v-dialog>
          <!-- Snackbar here -->
          <v-snackbar
            v-model="snackbar"
          >
            {{ snackbarText }}
          </v-snackbar>
        </v-toolbar>
      </template>
      <template v-slot:item.actions="{ item }">
        <v-icon
          small
          class="mr-2"
          @click="editItem(item)"
        >
          mdi-pencil
        </v-icon>
        <v-icon
          small
          @click="deleteItem(item)"
        >
          mdi-delete
        </v-icon>
      </template>
      <template v-slot:no-data>
        No data
      </template>
    </v-data-table>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

**Script:**

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: () => ({
    dialog: false,
    dialogDelete: false,
    snackbar: false,
    snackbarText: 'Item has been successfully deleted',
    headers: [
      {
        text: 'Dessert (100g serving)',
        align: 'start',
        sortable: false,
        value: 'name',
      },
      { text: 'Calories', value: 'calories' },
      { text: 'Fat (g)', value: 'fat' },
      { text: 'Carbs (g)', value: 'carbs' },
      { text: 'Protein (g)', value: 'protein' },
      { text: 'Photo', value: 'photoURL', sortable: false },
      { text: 'Actions', value: 'actions', sortable: false },
    ],
    desserts: [],
    editedIndex: -1,
    editedItem: {
      name: '',
      calories: 0,
      fat: 0,
      carbs: 0,
      protein: 0,
      photoURL: 0,
    },
    defaultItem: {
      name: '',
      calories: 0,
      fat: 0,
      carbs: 0,
      protein: 0,
      photoURL: 0,
    },
  }),

  computed: {
    formTitle () {
      return this.editedIndex === -1 ? 'New Item' : 'Edit Item'
    },
  },

  watch: {
    dialog (val) {
      val || this.close()
    },
    dialogDelete (val) {
      val || this.closeDelete()
    },
  },

  created () {
    this.initialize()
  },

  methods: {
    initialize () {
      this.desserts = [
        {
          name: 'Frozen Yogurt',
          calories: 159,
          fat: 6.0,
          carbs: 24,
          protein: 4.0,
          // photoURL: 'IMAGE HERE',
          photoURL: './assets/images/desserts/1.jpg',
          // photoURL: require('@/assets/images/desserts/1.jpg'),
        },
        {
          name: 'Ice cream sandwich',
          calories: 237,
          fat: 9.0,
          carbs: 37,
          protein: 4.3,
          photoURL: 'IMAGE HERE',
        },
        {
          name: 'Eclair',
          calories: 262,
          fat: 16.0,
          carbs: 23,
          protein: 6.0,
          photoURL: 'IMAGE HERE',
        },
        {
          name: 'Cupcake',
          calories: 305,
          fat: 3.7,
          carbs: 67,
          protein: 4.3,
          photoURL: 'IMAGE HERE',
        },
        {
          name: 'Gingerbread',
          calories: 356,
          fat: 16.0,
          carbs: 49,
          protein: 3.9,
          photoURL: 'IMAGE HERE',
        },
        {
          name: 'Jelly bean',
          calories: 375,
          fat: 0.0,
          carbs: 94,
          protein: 0.0,
          photoURL: 'IMAGE HERE',
        },
        {
          name: 'Lollipop',
          calories: 392,
          fat: 0.2,
          carbs: 98,
          protein: 0,
          photoURL: 'IMAGE HERE',
        },
        {
          name: 'Honeycomb',
          calories: 408,
          fat: 3.2,
          carbs: 87,
          protein: 6.5,
          photoURL: 'IMAGE HERE',
        },
        {
          name: 'Donut',
          calories: 452,
          fat: 25.0,
          carbs: 51,
          protein: 4.9,
          photoURL: 'IMAGE HERE',
        },
        {
          name: 'KitKat',
          calories: 518,
          fat: 26.0,
          carbs: 65,
          protein: 7,
          photoURL: 'IMAGE HERE',
        },
      ]
    },

    editItem (item) {
      this.editedIndex = this.desserts.indexOf(item)
      this.editedItem = Object.assign({}, item)
      this.dialog = true
    },

    deleteItem (item) {
      this.editedIndex = this.desserts.indexOf(item)
      this.editedItem = Object.assign({}, item)
      this.dialogDelete = true
    },

    deleteItemConfirm () {
      this.desserts.splice(this.editedIndex, 1)
      this.closeDelete()
      this.snackbar = true
    },

    close () {
      this.dialog = false
      this.$nextTick(() => {
        this.editedItem = Object.assign({}, this.defaultItem)
        this.editedIndex = -1
      })
    },

    closeDelete () {
      this.dialogDelete = false
      this.$nextTick(() => {
        this.editedItem = Object.assign({}, this.defaultItem)
        this.editedIndex = -1
      })
    },

    save () {
      if (this.editedIndex > -1) {
        Object.assign(this.desserts[this.editedIndex], this.editedItem)
      } else {
        this.desserts.push(this.editedItem)
      }
      this.close()
    },
  },
})
```

Comment: You can try using custom click events on icons and then write your own code to input the image from the user. https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/text-fields/#icon-events

Answer (score 0):

When you upload file, it does not create only url. If you want to see your image, just use:

```
URL.createObjectURL(this.editedItem.photoURL);
```